# Fill a Java Class with GSon Builder and JSon File

Tags: java, gson

I want to fill a Java Class with an external JSon File and I works with Gson Builder. But my Java class won´t be filled by the value, which i have declared in the JSon File. What is the problem? Thanks for helping !

This is my Json File:

```
{
"tstamp": "2012-11-21 18:00",
"id": 123,
"publicationList": [
    {
        "id": "1L",
        "state": "PublicationState.IMMEDIATELY",
        "channel": "PublicationChannel.TIMETABLE", 
        "startDate": "2001-12-17 18:00",
        "endDate": "2001-12-17 18:00"
    },
    {
        "id": "2L",
        "state": "PublicationState.IMMEDIATELY",
        "channel": "PublicationChannel.NVS", 
        "startDate": "2001-12-17 18:00",
        "endDate": "2001-12-17 18:00"
    },
    {
        "id": "3L",
        "state": "PublicationState.IMMEDIATELY",
        "channel": "PublicationChannel.NVS", 
        "startDate": "2001-12-17 18:00",
        "endDate": "2001-12-17 18:00"
    }
]
}
```

This is my Gson Builder and GSon Instance Creator:

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
            .registerTypeAdapter(Publication.class,
                    new PublicationInstanceCreator()).create();

 public class PublicationInstanceCreator implements
    InstanceCreator<PublicationDto> {

     @Override
     public PublicationDto createInstance(Type type) {

         return new PublicationDto();

     }

 }
```

This is the Java Class PublicattionDto:

```
public class PublicationDto{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;

    private PublicationState state = PublicationState.IMMEDIATELY;

    private PublicationChannel channel;

    private Date startDate;

    private Date endDate;


    //getter and setter methods

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your error ? The main POJO object is also missing in your code.

Assuming this object is `Publications`, you only have to use

```
Publications p = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").create().fromJson(json, Publications.class);
```

Your adapter won't work. Plus I think the IDs with 'L' won't work too (drop the L), GSon will cast the number into the correct Long type.